# Easier way of calculating the determinant for this matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant, circulant-matrices

I have to calculate the determinant of this matrix:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a&b&c&d\\b&c&d&a\\c&d&a&b\\d&a&b&c
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Is there an easier way of calculating this rather than the long regular way?

Comment: I think $R_4  \to  R_1 + R_2 + R_3 + R_4, C_1  \to C_4 - C_1 , C_2  \to C_4 - C_2, C_3  \to C_4 - C_3$  makes a bit easier by introducing 3 zeros at first, second, third column of fourth row.

Comment: @experimentX  This way is much nicer than the solution I posted (and deleted) and actually correct, my block diagonal thought turns out to be false.

Comment: @muzzlator sorry, i couldn't see ... when I clicked load answer, it was already deleted.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can easily transform your matrix to a *circulant matrix*
$$
M=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
a&b&c&d\\
d&a&b&c\\
c&d&a&b\\
b&c&d&a
\end{array}\right)
$$
by carrying out obvious row swaps. The eigenvalue theory of circulant matrices is completely known. In the $4\times 4$ case the eigenvalues of $M$ are
$$
\lambda_1=a+b+c+d,\ \lambda_2=a+bi-c-di,\ \lambda_3=a-b+c-d\ \text{and}\ \lambda_4=a-bi-c+di.
$$
The determinant of a matrix is the product of its eigenvalues so
$$
\det M=\lambda_1\lambda_2\lambda_3\lambda_4.
$$

Comment: Observe that (in case $a,b,c,d$ are all real) the eigenvalues $\lambda_2$ and $\lambda_4$ are compex conjugates, so their product is always real.

Comment: The eigenvalue theory comes from the observation that the eigenvalues of the matrix
$$T=\pmatrix{0&1&0&0\cr0&0&1&0\cr0&0&0&1\cr1&0&0&0\cr}$$ are $1,i,-1$ and $-i$. Hardly a surprise as $T^4=I_4$. Here
$$M=aI+bT+cT^2+dT^3,$$ so the claim follows.

Answer (score 3):

A pedestrian's solution (experimentX's suggestion below the question).

Add the first three columns to the fourth:
\begin{align*}
\begin{vmatrix}
a&b&c&d\\b&c&d&a\\c&d&a&b\\d&a&b&c
\end{vmatrix} &
=(a+b+c+d)\begin{vmatrix}
a&b&c&1\\b&c&d&1\\c&d&a&1\\d&a&b&1
\end{vmatrix} 
\end{align*}
Subtract the second row from the first row, the third row from the second row and the fourth row from the third row; develop after the fourth column:

\begin{align*} 
&=(a+b+c+d)
\begin{vmatrix}
a-b&b-c&c-d \\
b-c&c-d&d-a \\
c-d&d-a&a-b 
\end{vmatrix} \\
\end{align*}

Add the first column to the third column:

\begin{align*}
&=(a+b+c+d)(a-b+c-d)
\begin{vmatrix}
a-b&b-c&1 \\
b-c&c-d&-1 \\
c-d&d-a&1 
\end{vmatrix} 
\end{align*}
Add the second row to the first row and the third row to the second row:
\begin{align*}
&=(a+b+c+d)(a-b+c-d)
\begin{vmatrix}
a-c&b-d&0 \\
b-d&c-a&0 \\
c-d&d-a&1 
\end{vmatrix} \\
&=-(a+b+c+d)(a-b+c-d)[(a-c)^2+(b-d)^2].
\end{align*}